# Enter multiple rows explicitly in single select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am testing a query and want to use `SELECT` to get some initial data like so:

```
SELECT 1,2,3
    UNION
SELECT 2,3,4
```

Is there a syntax to fold these two selects into one or do I have to use a `UNION` statement for each row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use values clause

```
select t.*  from (values(1,2,3), (2,3,4)) as t(col1,col2,col3)
```

Comment: Yep: [Table Value Constructor](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/table-value-constructors-in-sql-server-2008/)

Comment: And the link for Postgres [`VALUES`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-values.html) expression

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the result as one result set then you have to use union/union all